# Is this property a reference or a copy and how it would behave in memory?

Tags: c#, pointers, memory, reference, copy

Say I have a dictionary of `Something`:

```
private Dictionary<uint, Something> _somethingList = new Dictionary<uint, Something>();
```

`Something` being, for example:

```
class Something
{
    public uint Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // ... more stuff here
}
```

And then I have `Another` class:

```
class Another
{
    public Another(uint id, string name, Something connection)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Connection = connection;
    }

    public uint Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Something Connection { get; set; }
}
```

And using it like this:

```
var test = new Another(1, "Test", _somethingList[1]);
```

Will `Connection` be a reference or copy of the value with key 1 from the `_somethingList` dictionary or it will create a new memory for it?

I guess what I am asking is, how it would behave in memory, as in, would it duplicate the property data in memory or would it be like a pointer to the actual `_somethingList[1]`? Or how can I verify this myself(I mean if I break point is there something that indicates whether its a copy or reference or w/e)?

Comment: That will be reference and will not create new memory. If you will change member of `_somethingList[1]` somewhere else. it will be changed in `test` object's `Connection` too.

Comment: @Amit thanks for the comment, so `Connection` would be like a pointer to the actual value of the dictionary?

Comment: Yes. Connection will just carry the reference of `_somethingList[1]` . it will not hold actual data.

Comment: @Amit alright thanks, I was afraid that it might have been copying it over instead of referencing it and was wondering if there is a way to recognize it by break pointing at it

Comment: @Guapo In visual studio, you right click in the local window and select ["Make Object ID"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/03/04/make-object-id/) which will assign a unique integer to the specific object. Then you can distinguish whether two references point to the exact same object.

Comment: @Guapo I have answered with working code, you can try it out at your environment.

Comment: @mikez that is awesome, exactly what I was looking for! Can you perhaps add that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your data structure and class design, If you perform following line of codes. You will get to know that, in property `Connection` of `Another` class you are actually having a reference of `_somethingList[1]` not a copy.

***Editing my Answer with profiler result so you can get the idea of Memory usage too***

changed something class (which is just to magnify memory usage and you don't have to consider it in your actual code.

```
public class Something
{
    public uint Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<string> stringList { get; set; }

    public Something (uint id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;

        stringList = new List<string>();
        for(long i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            stringList.Add(i.ToString());
        }
    }

}
```

and logic is,

```
        DateTime nowDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        Dictionary<uint, Something> _somethingList = new Dictionary<uint, Something>();

        Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now - nowDateTime).TotalSeconds.ToString() + " Creating List _somethingList");

            //slowly creating lsit so you can get memory usage incresing in profiler
        for (uint i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            _somethingList.Add(i, new Something(i, "amit" + i.ToString()));
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now - nowDateTime).TotalSeconds.ToString() +  " Before creating test object");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5 * 1000);
        Another test = new Another(1, "Test", _somethingList[1]);
        Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now - nowDateTime).TotalSeconds.ToString() + "  After creating test object");

        Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now - nowDateTime).TotalSeconds.ToString() + "  Name before editing:" + test.Connection.Name);
        _somethingList[1].Name = "EditedName";
        Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now - nowDateTime).TotalSeconds.ToString() + "  Name after editing:" + test.Connection.Name);
```

and output is,

[image]

you can see, on creating every object of `somethingList` there is significant increment of memory usage in profiler observation,

but from second 9 to 14, when we are setting reference of `_somethingList[1]` to `Connection` there is no memory increasing in profiler result. that means it was just reference setting no memory allocation.

Comment: +1 thanks for the detailed answer, it does assure me memory wise its fine but what I was really after is what mike posted on the comments, it shows me how to trace back to the origin of it and even lets me compare which is pretty cool. Nevertheless thanks for reassuring me of everything.

Answer (score 0):

All classes in .net are reference types, therefore you will have a reference to the same dictionary entry and not a copy of it. if you're looking for a copy then use scruct instead of the class. structs are value types but have smaller scope and more limited behavior when compared to classes.

If you in fact need to copy by value and keep the class then you probably can benefit from some deep cloning method and clone you're object before passing onto the constructor. there are numerous implementations of deep and shallow clone out there and you can easily find one online.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 basic types:  Reference and value.  `Dictionary` is not important because you extract a value from `Dictionary` and pass that.

`_somethingList[1]` =>  returns `Something` object which in turns get's passed to `Another.ctor`

Think of it as:

```
Something somethingObj = _somethingList[1];
var test = new Another(1, "Test", somethingObj);
```

The way these objects behave in memory is a bit tricky.  You are working in a managed language which means you don't have direct control over the memory or optimizations.

You can check for **identity** and **equality**.  Identity means the locations (a location is loosely a memory address with a type) are the same.  If two objects have the same identity then they are also always equal.  Equality means the values stored in the variables are the same, but the variables themselves may or may not be stored in the same location.

Identity can be checked using `Object.ReferenceEquals`. 
Equality can be checked using `Object.Equals`.

In this example I show how you can check for identity and equality against `Something`.

```
void Main()
{   
    var a = new Something();
    var b = a;
    var c = new Something();

    Object.Equals(a,b);//True
    Object.Equals(b,c);//False
    Object.Equals(a,c);//False
    Object.ReferenceEquals(a,b);//True
    Object.ReferenceEquals(b,c);//False
    Object.ReferenceEquals(a,c);//False

    var d = M(a);//Pass a to M and check the identity of what comes back

    Object.ReferenceEquals(a, d);//True
}

public static Something M(Test e)
{
    e.SomeVariable = 10;//a and e now refer to the same object location
    //e = new Test();//a and e refer to different objects when you do this.  This will not be reflected back to the caller unless you use ref parameters
    return e;
}

public class Something { public int SomeVariable {get;set;} }
```

Again, things get tricky when dealing with optimizations and [ref parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref).